# Python 2.x and 3.x sourceless .pyc deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, python-2.x

In Python 2.x the `.pyc` files are stored inside the same directory as the source `.py` file. In Python 3.2+ the `.pyc` files are stored inside the `__pycache__` directory.

If the code is written properly, it can be run by both interpreters and the `.pyc` files can coexist fine. But as soon as I want to get rid of the source code I get a problem: the Python 2.x interpreter still imports the correct `.pyc` file but the Python 3.2+ interpreter refuses to import its compiled `.pyc` from the `__pycache__` directory and tries to import the `.pyc` file from the previous version and fails as the magic numbers do not match.

Is it possible to make both Python interpreters happy without exposing the source code?

**[Updated]**

I tried this (it looked like a solution):

1. Deploy sources as usual
2. Compile each .py file with Python 2.x compiler (this will produce `.pyc` file in the same directory)
3. Compile each .py file with Python 3.2+ compiler (this will produce `.pyc` file in the `__pycache__` directory)
4. Clear the `.py` file contents while preserving its modification date

The Python 2 interpreter is happy. The Python 3 interpreter suspects that the source is modified and recompiles the modified source. What's the reason for it to recompile? Does it store the source file size as well? The checksum?

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 will make use of `.pyc` files in the same location if there is no `.py` file or `__pycache__` directory. Note that Python 3 [explicitly refuses to load `__pycache__` files if the source file is missing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-3-pycache-foo-magic-pyc-with-no-source), for source-less distributions, only the [legacy locations are supported](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#case-4-legacy-pyc-files-and-source-less-imports).

The [`compileall` module and command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) can be told to produce `.pyc` files in the same directory for that very reason:

```
python -m compileall -b
```

but take into account that byte cache files remain Python-version specific. You'll have to produce and distribute cache files per Python bytecache magic number (which generally changes with each .x release).

So no, you can't have `.pyc` source-less distributions that work on multiple Python versions. That was never the case before Python 3.2 either, Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, and 3.1 `.pyc` bytecache files each have a unique bytecache version number, the 'magic number' Python will complain about if you give it a `.pyc` file from another version.